# Attribute Error getpeername during scp connection attempt

Tags: python, attributeerror, scp

I'm trying to save a file from a remote server to my local pc.
I've tried the following code:

import scp

```
client = scp.SCPClient("ip", "username", "password")

# and then
client.transfer('remote/file', 'C:\folder')
```

but doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\localfp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scp.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.peername = self.transport.getpeername()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getpeername'
```

can you explain me what is this kind of error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this solution:

```
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("IP address",username="xxxx", password="xxx")
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.get('remote path', 'local path')
```

Answer (score 0):

`SCPClient` does not take arguments like ip, username or password. It accepts transport. Check the constructor.

`def __init__(self, transport, buff_size=16384, socket_timeout=10.0, progress=None, progress4=None, sanitize=_sh_quote):`

Connect using paramiko and pass the object to SCPClient.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

with SSHClient() as ssh:
    # ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("ip", username="username", password="password")

    with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as client:
        client.transfer('remote/file', 'C:\folder')
```

Comment: ciao, thanks for the reply. I've tried this and I got this error 
 
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: I edited it in place, this should work